# Optional and dynamic service parameter

Tags: php, symfony

I use a software (shopware) which use some Symfony components so I think this question is mainly Symfony related.

I came across a problem (or uncertainty) when i was creating a service in the services.xml that has optional or dynamic parameters that aren't available in the service.xml.

Two Examples

1. Create own monolog instance

Beside the systems default monolog instance i want an own monolog instance for my plugin with different handlers and configuration.

In my services.xml i have something like this:

```
<service id="my_plugin.monolog.handler.rotating_file_debug" class="Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler" public="false">
   <argument>%kernel.logs_dir%/myplugin_debug.log</argument>
   <argument>14</argument>
</service>

<service id="my_plugin.monolog.handler.rotating_file_error" class="Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler" public="false">
   <argument>%kernel.logs_dir%/myplugin_error.log</argument>
   <argument>14</argument>
   <argument>%monolog.logger.constant.error%</argument>
   <argument>false</argument>
</service>

<service id="my_plugin.logger" class="Monolog\Logger">
   <argument>myplugin.logger</argument>
   <argument type="collection">
      <argument type="service" id="my_plugin.monolog.handler.rotating_file_error" />
      <argument type="service" id="my_plugin.monolog.handler.rotating_file_debug" />
   </argument>
</service>
```

This works great but now i want to add an additionally mail-handler **IF an error email-adress is available** (backend plugin-configuration).

The problem is that i don't know how to check this in the services.xml.

My solution was a factory-class so i modified the services.xml like this:

```
<service id="my_plugin.logger" class="Monolog\Logger">
   <factory class="MyPlugin\Components\Factory" method="createLogger" />
   <argument>myplugin.logger</argument>
   <argument type="collection">
      <argument type="service" id="my_plugin.monolog.handler.rotating_file_error" />
      <argument type="service" id="my_plugin.monolog.handler.rotating_file_debug" />
   </argument>
</service>
```

This works But feels wrong as if i have a logical issue here.

2. Api-Client

The Api-Client need apiUser, apiKey and apiUrl as constructor parameter. None of these values are available in the service.xml. I also create a factory method.

So my question is what would be the "best-practice" solution for
optional or dynamic parameters?

Do i have a logical problem or is a factory a good solution? 
What's about compiler-passes are these suitable for this case?

**Update 19.05**

I created a CompilerPass and it works but in the process-method i have no access to the DI-Container so i'm not able to access database through the service.

Is that a limitation or do i miss something?

**Update 19.05 #2**

Seems like it isn't intended to access DIC in CompilerPass so i can't access the needed backend configuration values.

I tried something different now:

// services.xml

```
<service id="my_plugin.logger" class="MyPlugin\Components\Logger">
   <argument>myplugin.logger</argument>
   <argument type="collection">
      <argument type="service" id="my_plugin.monolog.handler.rotating_file_critical" />
      <argument type="service" id="my_plugin.monolog.handler.rotating_file_error" />
      <argument type="service" id="my_plugin.monolog.handler.rotating_file_debug" />
   </argument>
   <argument type="collection"></argument>
   <argument type="service" id="shopware.plugin.config_reader" />
   <argument type="service" id="Config" />
</service>
```

// MyPlugin\Components\Logger

```
<?php
namespace MyPlugin\Components;

use Monolog\Formatter\HtmlFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\NativeMailerHandler;
use Shopware\Components\Plugin\DBALConfigReader;

class Logger
    extends \Monolog\Logger
{
    /** @var DBALConfigReader */
    private $pluginConfigReader;

    /** @var \Shopware_Components_Config */
    private $config;

    public function __construct($name, array $handlers = array(), array $processors = array(), DBALConfigReader $pluginConfigReader, \Shopware_Components_Config $config)
    {
        $this->pluginConfigReader = $pluginConfigReader;
        $this->config = $config;

        parent::__construct($name, $handlers, $processors);

        $pluginConfig = $this->pluginConfigReader->getByPluginName('MyPlugin');
        $errorEmail = $pluginConfig['critical_error_email'];

        if($errorEmail != "")
        {
            $this->addMailHandler($errorEmail);
        }
    }

    private function addMailHandler($recipient)
    {
        $mailHandler = new NativeMailerHandler(
            $recipient,
            $this->config->get('shopName').' - Critial Issue',
            $this->config->get('mail'),
            Logger::CRITICAL
        );

        $mailHandler->setFormatter(new HtmlFormatter());

        $this->pushHandler($mailHandler);
    }
}
```

Not sure if this solution is better then a factory but it works.
I'm still interesstet in feedback if someone has a better solution.

Comment: You can accomplish the first issue by dynamically updating your service using a compiler pass: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html

Comment: Ok this would be the preferred solution in this case? Shouldn't it also work for the second issue apiUser, apiKey and apiUrl are also in the database/part of plugin configuration.

Comment: I would expect the api stuff to be defined as parameters in app/config.yml and accessed with id='%apiKey%'  You could also setup a full fledged configuration system for your bundle: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/configuration.html

Comment: At this point it's differ from plain symfony i guess.There is no app/config.yml respectively it's a plugin for end customers so configuration  takes place in a backend. But i will try out compiler passes, maybe it's the right solution for both issues. Thanks.

Comment: Compiler passes are part of the framework.  If you are not creating a framework bundle then they won't be of much help.  I think we may have a communication gap here.

Comment: I will research (hopfully) tomorrow if shopware supports compiler passes. (http://symfony.com/projects/shopware)

Comment: I'm not able to solve my issue using a compiler pass yet. In principle it works but i have no access to the database (di-container) inside my process-method.